# Unable to run rails s on osx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

When I run my code on osx, I get following error. Same code works fine on Linux. What could be wrong?

```
Exiting
/Users/jagratishringi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@voylla/gems/polyglot-0.3.3/lib/polyglot.rb:63:in `require': no such file to load -- psych (LoadError)
    from /Users/jagratishringi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@voylla/gems/polyglot-0.3.3/lib/polyglot.rb:63:in `require'
    from /Users/jagratishringi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@voylla/gems/activesupport-3.1.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
    from /Users/jagratishringi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@voylla/gems/activesupport-3.1.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load_dependency'
    from /Users/jagratishringi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@voylla/gems/activesupport-3.1.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
    from /Users/jagratishringi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@voylla/gems/activesupport-3.1.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/jagratishringi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@voylla/gems/activesupport-3.1.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
    from /Users/jagratishringi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/yaml.rb:16:in `yamler='
    from /Users/jagratishringi/work/voylla_website/config/environment.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/jagratishringi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@voylla/gems/polyglot-0.3.3/lib/polyglot.rb:63:in `require'
    from /Users/jagratishringi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@voylla/gems/polyglot-0.3.3/lib/polyglot.rb:63:in `require'
    from /Users/jagratishringi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@voylla/gems/activesupport-3.1.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
    from /Users/jagratishringi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@voylla/gems/activesupport-3.1.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load_dependency'
    from /Users/jagratishringi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@voylla/gems/activesupport-3.1.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:i
```

Answer (score 0):

In Gemfile

Please add

1. `gem "psych", "~> 2.0.0"`
2. `bundle install`
3. `rails s`

Thanks